# find the equation of the tangent plane $x+y+z=5e^{xyz}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the equation of the tangent at the point(0,0,5) and find the equation of the normal line.

We never covered this in class, I think this requires implicit differentiation and if that is the case I don't know how to do it

$5e^{xyz}-x-y-z=0$

$f_x = 5yze^{xyz}-1$

$f_y = 5xze^{xyz}-1$

$f_z = 5xye^{xyz}-1$

plugging in my points in the partials gives:

$F_x(0,0,5)=-1$

$F_y (0,0,5)=-1$

$f_Z(0,0,5)=-1$

now for the equation of the plane:

$-1(x-0),-1(y-0)+-1(z-5)$ gives $x+y+z=5$

Comment: Hint: Rewrite the equation in the form $f(x,y,z)=0$. Then I bet you've covered how to find the normal vector to this surface.

Comment: yep i did i just made an arthematic error and got the correct answer in both of the problems that were like these

Comment: Yippee! Good! {}